# Magically bridge a device to my network via my phone?

Tags: ios, networking, arduino, raspberry-pi, iot

I'm building a headless raspberry-pi based device that I'm sending my dad who isn't super tech savvy. The device needs to scan for his network and connect to it somehow once it boots. He won't be able to plug in any keyboard, mouse or display. 
There is probably a better way to do this, but what about this?

Is there some existing way to have the Pi create an ad-hoc network, which allows my phone to connect to it directly by selecting it as a wireless network, and then somehow get a mobile app on my phone to share his home network's SSID and password?

In other words,

- Pi creates ad hoc network "MyPi"
- User switches mobile phone wifi network to "MyPi"
- With phone connected to Pi, Pi scans for networks and user picks network, enters password via mobile app
- Pi tries to connect to the home network with the password

Comment: This site is for programming questions. This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to create a mobile app or script to connect something to a network. Just because it involves hardware doesn't mean I don't need help with software.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but I rather doubt that you want a simple affirmative answer. Just write the program, but don't expect anyone here to write it for you.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible and for ideas, not a line-by-line implementation. I learned that the Chromecast apparently does what I'm asking, so yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to set up a hotspot on you phone and connect the Pi to the hotspot; then you could edit the network config files via an SSH app on your phone.
I have never tested whether or not it is possible, but it should be.

Comment: Good idea. Or maybe I could program the Pi to scan for a specific network named "Phone" and send him instructions on how to set up a hotspot on his phone named "Phone" and set a prescribed password.  Once the Pi powers up and finds the "Phone" hotspot, it'll use the password to hook up. I'l try it.